# Why does this error concern another class?

Tags: java, compiler-errors

When I compile Computer.java my terminal says

```
./Game.java:87: error: variable i is already defined in constructor Game(Player[],long,long)
        for(int i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++)
                ^
```

Why does the error concern another class? The for loop the terminal is referring to belongs to line 87 of Game.java.

Edit: I fixed the error and now both classes compile.

Comment: What's interesting here is the **error** is in `Game.java` on line 87 of **`Game.java`** (**not** `Computer.java`).

Answer (score 1):

Seems you imported `Game.java` to `Computer.java`, so this error occurs when compiling `Computer.java`.

You have already declared a variable `i` in the same scope(in `Game.java`'s constructor), so you do not need declare it again.

You can change it to:

```
for(i = 0; i < this.players.length; i++)
```

Comment: I don't see how this is helpful. Perhaps you should read my question more closely.

Comment: @PiKindOfGuy Seems you imported Game.java to Computer.java, so this error occurs when compiling Computer.java.